# How to listen to changes made to location services React Native with Expo?

Tags: react-native, geolocation, expo

I am building an app using React Native with Expo and from the documentation provided here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location.html

I used the code sample in the documentation and I am supposed to get location permission access prompt and when granted the location services should be automatically enabled on the device to get the current location.

On my Android S6 edge test device I only get the prompt and when I press allow I get a warning that location services are not enabled.

So is there a way to programatically enable location services ?

Here is my code:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    location: false,
  };
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.askForUserPermissionToGetCurrentLocation();
}

async askForUserPermissionToGetCurrentLocation() {
  // Ask for user's permission to access location settings
  let { status } = await 
  Expo.Permissions.askAsync(Expo.Permissions.LOCATION);
  console.log(status);
  // User denied access
  if (status !== "granted") {
    console.log("denied");

  // Otherwise, access granted
  } else {
    console.log("permission granted");
    // Get the location
    let location = await Expo.Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
    console.log(location);
    this.setState({ location: location });
}
```

}

Render method is just a text to display the longitude and latitude of the returned location.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method [`Expo.Location.watchPositionAsync(options, callback)`](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/location.html#expolocationwatchpositionasyncoptions-callback) to get a callback when the user's location is updated.